# How to convert a number with a value of 1.10 to floating point value and preserve the zeroes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a number with a value of 1.10 to a floating point value and preserve the zeroes. How can I achieve this in JavaScript.

1.10 when outputting and assigning the last 0 is lost, the result is 1.1, how to make sure that 0 is not lost when assigning in JavaScript.

Comment: Isn't floating point by definition imprecise for certain values? You could convert your number to an int (`* 100`) and store that instead.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but if it's about storing the money amount, you can go with `yourNumber.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: From a number point of view, `1.10` and `1.1` are the same

Comment: @RoboRobok 
I need to assign a value exactly what I got, but when assigning where 0 is present at the end, it is lost

Comment: Then do it as a string instead of number.

Comment: @RoboRobok 
I cast it to string via the toString method or use `$ {1.10}` but it also gets lost

Comment: It would help if you shared your code, so we could help you in that context.

Comment: @RoboRobok `let num = 123123.10
console.log(`${new Number(num)}`)
123123.1
console.log(new Number(num).toString())
123123.1`

Comment: When you do `let num = 123123.10`, the trailing `0` is already lost. Numeric types don't care about the zeroes at the end, basically.

Comment: @RoboRobok 
but how can I not lose 0, it is lost even when I bring it to string

Comment: Do you do any computation with this number? If you get the number as a string, then do some math with it and want the same precision back, you'd need to use `.toFixed()` on the final number, counting the precision of the original number manually. Please let me know in more detail what you're trying to do and I will post my answer when I understand your goal.

Comment: This question is related to formatting numbers. It's NOT lossless number format.

Comment: @GerardoLima neither is what OP is asking for "lossless format". They ask for how to make sure 1.10 is preserved as-is as a numeric value. Which isn't possible in JS, as numbers are numbers. They aren't "numbers but also have a formatting assigned to them" which other languages may have. Either you format the number as a string or cook up your own thing that holds value and a display version of it. However the display version will only be implementable as a formatted string as in the linked duplicate. Again - there is no "formatted numeric" in JS. In all cases, you'd have to format as string.

Comment: @GerardoLima moreover, there is hardly a reason to have such a "formatted numeric". There is no benefit to it. Calculating using `1.10` vs `1.1` would lead to an identical result. The formatting would be only there for display purposes. And any display data may as well be strings. There is certainly no benefit to keeping display data as non-string. Best case scenario is that raw value and display value are the same. But if they ever differ, you'd want some sort of string. Even if you want to format a boolean as, say "yes" and "no" that's not by formatting the primitive.

Comment: @VLAZ, please, refer to the title of this question. The reference to a lossless format for fractional numbers is misleading to users actually searching for it.

Comment: @GerardoLima I've edited to clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

From a number point of view, `1.10` and `1.1` are the same. The way to make this zero not to get lost is by working with strings instead of numbers, but then you lose many functionalities, like calculations.

Answer (score 2):

it can be done using `toFixed()` in javascript. for you number it can be done like this:

```
 console.log(1.10.toFixed(2))
```

Comment: if you are satisfied with this answer, then please accept this as your answer, it would help me grow my profile. Thank You